# getting tortoise svn version to python binary from py2exe

Tags: python, tortoisesvn, py2exe

I generated a py2exe binary of my project. I use TortoiseSVN. How do I extract the SVN Revision Number (which I later need to incorporate into the binary).  Do I need to implement the same in `Python`?  If so, how do I go about the same?

Comment: You want the version number of what exactly?

Comment: I need revision Build

Comment: I still don't know what you are asking. You want to know the version of SVN? The version of Tortoise? Or something from your SVN repo? Be precise

Comment: The above question has been rephrased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute this command:

```
svn info path/to/working/copy
```

and then parse the output. The output looks a little like this:

```
Path: path/to/working/copy
Working Copy Root Path: blah blah
URL: https://blah blah
Repository Root: https://blah blah
Repository UUID: blah blah
Revision: 42
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: blah blah
Last Changed Rev: 42
Last Changed Date: 2013-02-25 09:52:55 +0000 (Mon, 25 Feb 2013)
```

Use `subprocess.check_output` to execute the `svn` command and read in the output. Then parse it however you feel like. For example you could use a simple regex with `re` to find the information.

Comment: That's about it , Thanks David.